# How can you assign one IP per user?

Tags: linux, networking, users, ip

I'm building a headless Steam gameserver which utilises Steam in-home streaming to let two people play at the same time. The multiseat part of the setup is done and functional, but getting it to work wireless is quite troublesome.

Only one Steam client can enable in-home streaming at a time. This is most likely due to using the same ports and IP address. How can I assign each user their own IP address?

Streaming will only be done from within the home network. The machine itself already has 3 IPs on a single interface.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can assign different network configuration to a process using [linux network namespaces](https://lwn.net/Articles/580893/). In theory it should be possible to configure *PAM** to set each user in its own separate network namespace, but it is likely simpler to launch the application in question in its own namespace instead.

A common setup might describe creating a Linux bridge interface to connect the  namespaces to network. A bit simpler setup can be archived using *ipvlan* (included in kernel versions 3.19 and above) or *macvlan* device (for wireless you [can't use *macvlan*](https://superuser.com/a/1114044/751249)). Linux kernel documentation has [a detailed example](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ipvlan.txt) for setting up *ipvlan* in network namespace.

Following the example in the documentation:

1. Create a network namespace *ns0*

   ```
   ip netns add ns0
   ```
2. Create ipvlan slave on eth0 (master device)

   ```
   ip link add link eth0 ipvl0 type ipvlan mode l2
   ```
3. Assign slaves to the network namespace *ns0*

   ```
   ip link set dev ipvl0 netns ns0
   ```
4. Configure the slave device in network namespace *ns0*

   ```
   ip netns exec ns0 ip link set dev ipvl0 up
   ip netns exec ns0 ip link set dev lo up
   ip netns exec ns0 ip -4 addr add 127.0.0.1 dev lo
   ip netns exec ns0 ip -4 addr add $IPADDR dev ipvl0
   ip netns exec ns0 ip -4 route add default via $ROUTER dev ipvl0
   ```

   Provide host and router addresses in `$IPADDR` and `$ROUTER`.
5. Run your application in network namespace using `ip exec`

   ```
   ip netns exec ns0 <command>
   ```

   To run the command as different user, use the usual `su <user> -c -- <command>`.

---

* **EDIT:** From theory to practice: I've written a simple PAM module to demonstrate how to change the network namespace per user. You need to configure a network namepsace with `ip netns` like above and map specific users to specific a namespaces. Afterwards all user processes will be in their configured namespace instead of the default one. The code is hosted [**on github**](https://github.com/sebasth/pam_netns). Use at your own peril.

Comment: your second command does not work for me on `ubuntu 14.04` I only get: `Garbage instead of arguments "mode ...". Try "ip link help"`.

Comment: I've updated the answer with kernel version, Ubuntu 14.04 is doesn't seem to include recent enough kernel version. I can't think of a workaround that allows you to configure separate IP addresses when you are using wireless. If you are using Ethernet, you can just replace *ipvlan* with *macvlan* in command *3* and follow the rest of the example.

Comment: you mean in command 2? The variables `$IPADDR` and `$ROUTER` have to be provided by me or are those already set?

Comment: Indeed command *2*. You have to provide your own network configuration.

Comment: thank you for the explanations. A quick one for my understanding: How does the last command specify which namespace to run run the program under?

Comment: @Sim good catch, it didn't. Corrected the answer, the namespace needs to be specified after the exec keyword like in other parts of the example.