# Separate network namespaces for different users?

Tags: networking, arch-linux, network-namespaces

I'm running Arch Linux on a laptop. What I want to achieve:

- Multiple users
- When each user logs in on a tty (which could be while another user is logged in on another tty---they're all me), they're in their own network namespace
- They may start up a VPN connection, but they may also work without a VPN (so I don't think vopono will work for me)

Notes/constraints:

- There's no display-manager---all users log in on a tty and then startx. But I don't mind using one if that makes this easier somehow.
- I use linux-hardened so `CONFIG_USER_NS_UNPRIVILEGED` is disabled and I don't want to enable it via sysctl either.

What I've looked at: I think I want something like [pam_netns](https://github.com/sebasth/pam_netns) or [pam_usernet](https://github.com/rd235/libpam-net) but pam_netns seems to have been a [one-off thing 6 years ago](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/391295/how-can-you-assign-one-ip-per-user), and pam_usernet also hasn't been updated in 4 years.

Alternatively, is there a way to have vopono simply set up a separate network namespace for a user on login, but not connect to a VPN? It's fine if the user has to run a script to do this manually on login.

Comment: hm, maybe you can integrate this into systemd user.slice?

Answer (score 1):

(It's a bit worrying that there's no pre-existing software to do this---maybe that means I'm trying to solve the wrong problem here. I'm gonna re-ask a better question, but meanwhile here's my homegrown solution.)

Solutions below for both systemd and runit, and thanks to @Marcus Müller for getting me started on the systemd piece. Summary: create the network namespaces as root before calling agetty, and then call agetty, which calls login, which switches over to the individual user. Details below if they help anyone else:

### systemd

1. Use the answer in [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/391295/how-can-you-assign-one-ip-per-user) to write a script, say `/usr/local/sbin/ip-netns.sh`, to create or delete the namespace(s) depending on how it's called.
2. Per the [Arch wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd#Replacement_unit_files), create either `/etc/systemd/system/getty@.service.d/override.conf` to do this for all ttys, or `/etc/systemd/system/getty@tty2.service.d/override.conf` to do it just for tty2 (for example). The `override.conf` should say:

   ```
   [Service]
   ExecStartPre=/usr/local/sbin/ip-netns.sh create 2
   ExecStart=
   ExecStart=-ip netns exec ns2 /sbin/agetty -o '-p -- \\u' --noclear - $TERM
   ExecStartPost=/usr/local/sbin/ip-netns.sh delete 2
   ```

Notes:

1. The first (empty) `ExecStart=` is to clear the `ExecStart` from the original config file in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/getty@.service`.
2. Instead of `2` in the example above you can pass `%I` to `ip-netns.sh` if you want to do it for all namespaces. `%I` contains (in turn) "tty1", "tty2", etc. each time it's called. But then you need to convert the passed `%I` into the namespace names in `ip-netns.sh`.

### runit

It's a bit more straightforward because you're just editing a shell-script directly: `/etc/runit/sv/agetty-tty*/run`. You can either put the entire namespace-handling code in there, or have that script call `/usr/local/sbin/ip-netns.sh` as above.