# Separating work and personal network activity

Tags: networking, security, virtual-machine

I asked [a question here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/750920/separate-network-namespaces-for-different-users) that got no answers and only one comment (and then my own answer), so maybe I was asking the wrong question.

I use the same computer for work and for personal use. I keep the two under separate users, each with sandboxed browsers, but I'd also like to separate their network activity. Each may or may not need a VPN at the same time. What are some methods people have found useful to do this, and the pros and cons of each approach?

The approach I use, described in the other thread, is separate network namespaces for different users. I think this separates them somewhat, but it's probably trivial from a security perspective and it's a bit of a nuisance to set up.

I considered using Qubes for much greater isolation, but Qubes has a few constraints that are deal-breakers for me (e.g. no GPU passthrough, which makes Zoom lag).

I considered running separate VMs myself (i.e. without using Qubes), but that ended up being kinda hacky and not a great UX.

Any other ideas?

Comment: You dismissed pam_usernet as "too old" in the premises of the former question, without considering it could do the job. Does that mean you want to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I didn't "dismiss" it, I expressed a concern that it might not be actively maintained any more since the last update was 3 years ago. As I said in the other thread, the fact that I'm having to roll my own solution is making me nervous that I'm doing the wrong thing, which is why I asked this question.

Comment: "_As I said in the other thread_" - don't assume people will cross-reference for additional information. If you're asking a question here please provide all the necessary and relevant detail in that question

Comment: As I said in that very sentence, "the approach I use...is separate network namespaces for different users". I'm summarizing three different approaches I've considered/tried. In the context isn't that all that's necessary and relevant?

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is: *never* mix work and private on a single device. Whether it is a phone or a laptop, don't do it. There are a number of reasons for this.

A work-device may get policies from an employer enforced. These may contain anti data leak policies et cetera. There could be a remote wipe clean in that policy. You could use a virtual machine to contain these policies.

When there is a security incident, an employer may request to examine your laptop. In these cases, you cannot restrict the examiners to use only `work_uid` or the VM `work`, they'll go through the entire laptop. No form of separation, VMs, Qubes, even separate separate boot partitions will protect you from this.

You might get away by using a cloud service (DaaS, Desktop as a Service) like Amazon or Microsoft have.